# Recover resources after errors

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm currently in the process of building an application that receives thousands of small messages through a basic web service, the messages are published to a message queue (RabbitMQ). The application makes use of Dependancy Injection using StructureMap as its container.

I have a separate worker application that consumes the message queue and persists the messages to a database (SQL Server).

I have implemented the SQL Connection and RabbitMQ connections as singletons (Thread Local).

In an ideal world, this all works fine but if SQL Server or RabbitMQ connection is broken I need to reopen it, or potentially dispose and recreate/reconnect the resources.

I wrote a basic class to act as a factory that before it returns a resource, checks it is connected/open/working and if not, dispose it and recreate it - I'm not sure if this is "best practice" or if I'm trying to solve a problem that has already been solved.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how I could implement long running tasks that do a lot of small tasks (in my case a single INSERT statement) that don't require object instantiation for each task, but can gracefully recover from errors such as dropped connections?

RabbitMQ connections seem to be expensive and during high work loads I can quickly run out of handles so I'd like to reuse the same connection (per thread).

Answer (score 0):

The [Enterprise Library 5.0 Integration Pack for Windows Azure](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Azure&referringTitle=Home) contains a block for transient fault handling. It allows you to specify retry behavior in case of errors.

It was designed with Windows Azure in mind but I'm sure it would be easy to write a custom policy based on what it offers you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a connection factory for RabbitMQ that has a connection pool. It would be responsible for handing out connections to tasks. You should check to see that the connections are ok. If not, start a new thread that closes/cleans the connection then returns it to the thread pool. Meanwhile return a functioning connection to the user.

It sounds complicated but it's the pattern for working with hard to initialize resources.